# Error validating XML with XSD version 1.1 with Xerces

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd-1.1

I am trying to validate an XML with XSD 1.1. I am not an expert in this, in fact it is the first time I try to create an XSD to validate an XML.
It gives me the following error:
*s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of '#AnonType_modelomodelos' is invalid. Element 'assert'
is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.*

I have downloaded the Xerces 1.1 version from here. https://dlcdn.apache.org//xerces/j/binaries/

I need to validate that in the available, blocked and canceled elements only one of them can have the value 'definitive'. The others may not have a positive value or numeric.

This is the XML.

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<modelos xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="sima-modelo.xsd">
    <modelo>
        <tipologia>DIAGNOSTICO</tipologia>
        <claseBase>Autodiag</claseBase>
        <disponible>3</disponible>
        <bloqueado></bloqueado>
        <cancelado>definitivo</cancelado>
        <borradoFisico>false</borradoFisico>
    </modelo>
    <modelo>
        <tipologia>POL</tipologia>
        <claseBase>Policy</claseBase>
        <disponible>30</disponible>
        <bloqueado>10</bloqueado>
        <cancelado>0</cancelado>
        <borradoFisico>true</borradoFisico>
    </modelo>
    <modelo>
        <tipologia>COLAB</tipologia>
        <claseBase>RRHH</claseBase>
        <disponible>1104</disponible>
        <bloqueado>0</bloqueado>
        <cancelado>0</cancelado>
        <borradoFisico>true</borradoFisico>
    </modelo>
</modelos>
```

Another version of XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
           xmlns:xerces="http://xerces.apache.org"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           vc:minVersion="1.1">
           
    <xs:element name="modelos">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="modelo" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="tipologia" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="claseBase" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="disponible" type="Accion" />
                            <xs:element name="bloqueado" type="Accion" />
                            <xs:element name="cancelado" type="Accion" />
                            <xs:element name="borradoFisico" type="xs:boolean" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                    <xs:assert test="count(disponible[.='definitivo']) + count(bloqueado[.='definitivo']) + count(cancelado[.='definitivo']) = 1" />
                    <xs:assert test="not(disponible = bloqueado or disponible = cancelado or bloqueado = cancelado)" />
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:simpleType name="Accion">
        <xs:union>
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
            <xs:simpleType id="positiveInteger">
                <xs:restriction base="xs:nonNegativeInteger">
                    <xs:minInclusive value="0" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
                    <xs:enumeration value="definitivo" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:union>
    </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
           xmlns:xerces="http://xerces.apache.org"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           vc:minVersion="1.1">

    <xs:simpleType name="Accion">
        <xs:union>
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value=""/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
            <xs:simpleType id="positiveIntegerOrDefinitivo">
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="\d+|definitivo"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:union>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:element name="modelos">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="modelo" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="tipologia" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="claseBase" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="disponible" type="Accion"/>
                            <xs:element name="bloqueado" type="Accion"/>
                            <xs:element name="cancelado" type="Accion"/>
                            <xs:element name="borradoFisico" type="xs:boolean"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:assert test="( count(disponible[.='definitivo']) + count(bloqueado[.='definitivo']) + count(cancelado[.='definitivo']) ) = 1"/>
                        <xs:assert test="not(disponible = bloqueado or disponible = cancelado or bloqueado = cancelado)"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The last version of XSD with the same message.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
    xmlns:xerces="http://xerces.apache.org"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" vc:minVersion="1.1">

    <xs:element name="modelos" type="ModelosType"/>

    <xs:complexType name="ModelosType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="modelo" type="ModeloType" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="ModeloType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="tipologia" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="claseBase" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="disponible" type="Accion" />
            <xs:element name="bloqueado" type="Accion" />
            <xs:element name="cancelado" type="Accion" />
            <xs:element name="borradoFisico" type="xs:boolean" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:assert test="count(disponible[.='definitivo']) + count(bloqueado[.='definitivo']) + count(cancelado[.='definitivo']) = 1" />
        <xs:assert test="not(disponible = bloqueado or disponible = cancelado or bloqueado = cancelado)" />
    </xs:complexType>
    
    <xs:simpleType name="Accion">
        <xs:union>
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
            <xs:simpleType id="positiveInteger">
                <xs:restriction base="xs:nonNegativeInteger">
                    <xs:minInclusive value="0" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
                    <xs:enumeration value="definitivo" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:union>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

I am using Eclipse 2022-12 and I think that the XML editor does not correctly validate the XSD assertion.
*s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of '#AnonType_modelomodelos' is invalid. Element 'assert' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.*
[image]

I have the downloaded libraries of the Xerces version 2.12.2 xml schema 1.1 configured in the classpath.
These are the jars. They are right?.

```
ext-libs/resolver.jar
ext-libs/serializer.jar
ext-libs/xml-apis.jar
ext-libs/xercesImpl.jar
ext-libs/org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor_1.2.1.jar
ext-libs/cupv10k-runtime.jar
ext-libs/icu4j.jar
```

I have searched Maven for the libraries but apparently they do not support XSD 1.1

This is the result of the validation with the schema that you tell me you have modified:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-assertion: Assertion evaluation ('count(*[local-name()=('blocked','cancelled','available') and text()='final']) eq 1') for element 'modelo' on schema type '#AnonType_modelomodelos' did not succeed.
```

Validation method

```
static final String W3C_XML_SCHEMA_11_NS_URI = "http://www.w3.org/XML/XMLSchema/v1.1";

    public static boolean validateXMLSchema(String xsdPath, String xmlPath) {

        try {
            SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(W3C_XML_SCHEMA_11_NS_URI);
            Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new File(xsdPath));
            Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
            validator.validate(new StreamSource(new File(xmlPath)));
        } catch (IOException | SAXException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error validando 'modelos.xml' {}: ", xmlPath, e);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The complete rules are:

We have a list of models, each model with the following properties:

- typology: allows a string, is required.
- BaseClass: allows a string, is required.
- disponible: allows positive numbers or the string 'definitivo'.
- bloqueado: allows positive numbers or the string 'definitivo'.
- cancelado: allows positive numbers or the string 'definitivo'.
- borradoFisico: boolean.
- The following rules are for the *disponible*, *bloqueado* and *cancelado* properties: Only one of them can have the value 'definitivo'.
- They can have a value of 0, any positive numeric value or empty.
- If *disponible* is equal *definitivo* and *bloqueado* + *cancelado* != 0, then custom error.
- If *bloqueado* is equal to *definitivo* and *cancelado* is != 0, then custom error.

Comment: Please edit your question, and add your Java code for the XSD validation

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky added java code and validation result. Thanks

Comment: Is the sample instance document you have posted supposed to be valid for all `modelo`s or is it supposed to be invalid? I guess the conditions tried so far rather need `le 1` to implement `I need to validate that in the available, blocked and canceled elements only one of them can have the value 'definitive'`, the current attempts require exactly one of the elements to have the value `definitivo`.

Comment: Try to formulate your rules as XPath asserts. Keep in mind that doing simple string comparisons on union types might give type errors. Based on your extended list of requirements I still think that the current suggestion will assert the "The following rules are for the disponible, bloqueado and cancelado properties: Only one of them can have the value 'definitivo'." if `le 1` is used instead of `eq 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following XSD.

As @MartinHonnen already mentioned, the asserts were in the wrong location.

- I modified the 1st assert.
- Please clarify business rule(s) for the 2nd assert.

You can get the original **Xerces2 Java 2.12.2 (XML Schema 1.1)** here: [The Apache Xerces™ Project - Downloads](https://xerces.apache.org/mirrors.cgi)

I am using **Oxygen XML Developer v.26.0**. It is an XML IDE.

So, the XSD below is legit. It is tested, and working perfectly fine in Oxygen. Your XML sample is invalid because of the 2nd assert.

As @MartinHonnen already pointed out, the 2nd assert is using XML elements that belong to *Accion* user defined data type. It is using a **union** of different built-in data types: *"xs:string", "xs:nonNegativeInteger", "xs:token"*. That's why the 2nd assert is constantly failing the validation.

When I commented out the 2nd assert, your XML became valid against the XSD.

**XSD 1.1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
           xmlns:xerces="http://xerces.apache.org"
           elementFormDefault="qualified" vc:minVersion="1.1">
    <xs:element name="modelos">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="modelo" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="tipologia" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="claseBase" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="disponible" type="Accion"/>
                            <xs:element name="bloqueado" type="Accion"/>
                            <xs:element name="cancelado" type="Accion"/>
                            <xs:element name="borradoFisico" type="xs:boolean"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:assert test="count(*[local-name()=('bloqueado','cancelado','disponible') and text()='definitivo']) le 1"/>
                        <xs:assert test="not(disponible = bloqueado or disponible = cancelado or bloqueado = cancelado)"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:simpleType name="Accion">
        <xs:union>
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value=""/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
            <xs:simpleType id="positiveInteger">
                <xs:restriction base="xs:nonNegativeInteger">
                    <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
                    <xs:enumeration value="definitivo"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:union>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: I added complete rules at the end.Thansk

Comment: Thanks, I've checked it.
What other strategy can I use to validate these elements?
I have modified leaving only positiveInteger and definitivo type

Comment: You can try to cast all XML elements to the same data type, i.e. `xs:string,`  in the 2nd assert.

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution. Thanks to all!

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
    xmlns:xerces="http://xerces.apache.org" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    vc:minVersion="1.1"
>
    <xs:element name="modelos" type="ModelosType" />
    
    <xs:complexType name="ModelosType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="modelo" type="ModeloType"
                maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    
    <xs:complexType name="ModeloType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="tipologia" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="claseBase" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="disponible" type="Action" />
            <xs:element name="bloqueado" type="Action" />
            <xs:element name="cancelado" type="Action" />
            <xs:element name="borradoFisico" type="xs:boolean" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:assert
            test="(count(*[local-name()=('bloqueado','cancelado','disponible') and text()='definitivo']) eq 1 or
                   count(*[local-name()=('bloqueado','cancelado','disponible') and text()='definitivo']) eq 0 ) "
            xerces:message="Entre los elementos 'disponible', 'cancelado' y 'bloqueado', sólo uno de ellos puede tener el valor 'definitivo'. Revise el modelo"/>

        <!-- Validación: disponible = 'definitivo' entonces bloqueado y cancelado = 0 -->
        <xs:assert test="if (disponible='definitivo') then ((bloqueado='0' or bloqueado='') and (cancelado='0' or cancelado='') ) else true()"
                    xerces:message="Revise el modelo. Si disponible = 'definitivo' entonces bloqueado y cancelado = 0 o vacío"/>
                  
        <xs:assert test="if (bloqueado='definitivo') then (cancelado='0' or cancelado='') else true()"
                    xerces:message="Revise el modelo. Si bloqueado = 'definitivo' entonces cancelado = 0 o vacío"/>
                    
    </xs:complexType>
    
    <xs:simpleType name="Action">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="|0|[1-9][0-9]*|definitivo" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```